# get data datewise from mysql table

Tags: mysql

```
table
=====
id
firstname
lastname
registered_on int(11)
```

I want to make a query that counts the registered user date-wise so I can know how many users have registered on particular date

**My query**

```
SELECT registered_on,count(*) as cnt 
FROM websiteadmin_ext_jobseekers 
group by registered_on
```

and the result

```
2015-03-14count: 1
2015-03-14count: 1
2015-03-14count: 1
2015-03-14count: 1
2015-03-14count: 1
2015-03-14count: 1
2015-03-14count: 1
2015-03-14count: 1
2015-03-14count: 1
2015-03-14count: 1
2015-03-14count: 1
```

My problem is the data is not grouped by date it is displayed one by one

Comment: The datatype of `registered_on`  is int and looks like you are saving unix timestamp with `H:i:s` as well ?

Comment: data may be timstamp

Comment: GROUP BY DATE(`registered_on`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `registered_on`, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM `websiteadmin_ext_jobseekers` 
GROUP BY DATE(`registered_on`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datatype for the date column is

```
registered_on int(11)
```

Which looks like unix timestamp since in the PHP code you have

```
 echo date("Y-m-d",$row["registered_on"]);
```

So you need to modify the query as

```
SELECT 
registered_on,
count(*) as cnt 
FROM websiteadmin_ext_jobseekers 
group by date(FROM_UNIXTIME(registered_on))
```

The better would be as  eggyal  pointed out

```
SELECT 
date(FROM_UNIXTIME(registered_on))  as registered_on_date,
count(*) as cnt 
FROM websiteadmin_ext_jobseekers 
group by registered_on_date ;
```

Use the above query and in PHP use the index as `registered_on_date` no need to convert to `date` just use

```
echo $row["registered_on_date"];
```

Comment: Should really use the same expression in the select list too (indeed, could alias it there for use in the group by clause so as to avoid repeating oneself).

Comment: @ eggyal  you are correct, that should be much better :) Let me update.